# SQL to Access - Sum Case to IFF

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have following SQL code that needs to be converted to MS Access SQL view.

```
sum(case when DATEDIFF(d, A.DUEDATE, getdate()) < 31 
     and A.TYPE < 7 then A.AMT
when DATEDIFF(d, A.DOEDATE1, getdate()) < 31 
     and A.TYPE > 6 then A.AMT *-1
else 0
end) [Current]
```

I'm stuck after this:

```
Sum(IIF(Datediff(d, A.DUEDATE, Now())<31
```

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Comment: What is the GROUP BY filed(s)?

Comment: I didn't run the query in Access yet. Above statements work well in MySQL but I'm trying to convert it to Access SQL.

Comment: Nonsense, they cannot without some group by clause

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained better. That is not the end of the code. It's "Group by" none of the fields above. I simply want to convert the code referenced above. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Sum(IIF(Datediff(d, A.DUEDATE, Now()) < 31 AND A.Type < 7, A.AMT,
     IIF(DATEDIFF(d, A.DOEDATE1, getdate()) < 31 and A.TYPE > 6, -A.AMT, 0
        )
   )
```

Comment: How do you include the second criteria? (when DATEDIFF(d, A.DOEDATE1, getdate()) < 31 
     and A.TYPE > 6 then A.AMT *-1"

Comment: @user3654510 . . . Sure.  The complete statement is there now.